# How to use Criterion to measure performance of Haskell programs?

Tags: haskell, performance, haskell-criterion

I'm trying to measure the performance of a simple Haar DWT program using the Criterion framework. (It is erroneously slow, but I'll leave that for another question). I can't find any good documentation on the web, unfortunately. My two primary problems are

- How can one pass data from one benchmark to another? I want to time each stage of the program.
- How does the sampling work, and avoid lazy evaluation reusing its previous computations?

This source is relatively pared down; the first function `getRandList` generates a list of random numbers; `haarStep` transforms an input signal into differences and sums, and `haarDWT` calls the former and recurses on the sums. I'm trying to pass the `getRandList` to the `haarDWT` via lazy evaluation, but perhaps my usage is incorrect / unsupported. The timings don't seem to make sense.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}

import Control.Arrow
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as V
import System.Random
import Criterion.Main

invSqrt2 = 0.70710678118654752440

getRandList :: RandomGen g => g -> Int -> [Float]
getRandList gen 0 = []
getRandList gen n = v:rest where
    (v, gen') = random gen
    rest = getRandList gen' (n - 1)

haarStep :: V.Vector Float -> (V.Vector Float, V.Vector Float)
haarStep = (alternatingOp (-) &&& alternatingOp (+)) where
    alternatingOp op x = V.generate (V.length x `div` 2) (\i ->
        ((x V.! (2 * i)) `op` (x V.! (2 * i + 1))) * invSqrt2)

haarDWT :: V.Vector Float -> V.Vector Float
haarDWT xl@(V.length -> 1) = xl
haarDWT (haarStep -> (d, s)) = haarDWT s V.++ d

main = do
    gen <- getStdGen
    inData <- return $ getRandList gen 2097152
    outData <- return $ haarDWT (V.fromList inData)

    defaultMain [
        bench "get input" $ nf id inData,
        bench "transform" $ nf V.toList outData
        ]
    writeFile "input.dat" (unlines $ map show inData)
    writeFile "output.dat" (unlines $ map show $ V.toList outData)
```

Finally, I'm getting an error when I try to call it with `-s 1`; maybe this is just a Criterion bug.

```
Main: ./Data/Vector/Generic.hs:237 ((!)): index out of bounds (1,1)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**The posted benchmark is erroniously slow... or is it**

Are you sure it's erroneous?  You're touching (well, the "nf" call is touching) 2 million boxed elements - thats 4 million pointers.  You can call this erroneous if you want, but the issue is just what you think you're measure compared to what you really are measuring.

**Sharing Data Between Benchmarks**

Data sharing can be accomplished through partial application.  In my benchmarks I commonly have

```
let var = somethingCommon in
defaultMain [ bench "one" (nf (func1 somethingCommon) input1)
            , bench "two" (nf (func2 somethingCommon) input2)]
```

**Avoiding Reuse in the presences of lazy evaluation**

Criterion avoids sharing by separating out your function and your input.  You have signatures such as:

```
funcToBenchmark :: (NFData b) => a -> b
inputForFunc :: a
```

In Haskell every time you apply `funcToBenchmark inputForFunc` it will create a thunk that needs evaluated.  There is no sharing unless you use the same variable name as a previous computation.  There is no automatic memoization - this seems to be a common misunderstanding.

Notice the nuance in *what* isn't shared.  We aren't sharing the final result, but the *input* is shared.  If the generation of the input is what you want to benchmark (i.e. getRandList, in this case) then benchmark that and not just the identity + nf function:

```
main = do
    gen <- getStdGen
    let inData = getRandList gen size
        inVec = V.fromList inData
        size = 2097152
    defaultMain
      [ bench "get input for real" $ nf (getRandList gen) size
      , bench "get input for real and run harrDWT and listify a vector" $ nf (V.toList . haarDWT  . V.fromList . getRandList gen) size
      , bench "screw generation, how fast is haarDWT" $ whnf haarDWT inVec] -- for unboxed vectors whnf is sufficient
```

**Interpreting Data**

The third benchmark is rather instructive.  Lets look at what criterion prints out:

```
benchmarking screw generation, how fast is haarDWT
collecting 100 samples, 1 iterations each, in estimated 137.3525 s
bootstrapping with 100000 resamples
mean: 134.7204 ms, lb 134.5117 ms, ub 135.0135 ms, ci 0.950
```

Based on a single run, Criterion thinks it will take 137 seconds to perform it's 100 samples. About ten seconds later it was done - what happened?  Well, the first run forced all the inputs (`inVec`), which was expensive.  The subsequent runs found a value instead of a thunk, and thus we truely benchmarked `haarDWT` and not the `StdGen` RNG (which is known to be painfully slow).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's very helpful. I don't think your first point is correct though, even with the more accurate timing. They're unboxed vectors, so there should not be any pointer overhead. 3 * 2097152 * 4 bytes / 134 ms = 180 MB / sec which is not near the bandwidth of most CPUs as far as I know. (There should be approximately 2 reads and 1 write per data element written, which in this case are the difference components).

Comment: P.S. just curious, what CPU do you have? Mine is a little slower; even running on a Xeon X5680 server doesn't seem quite as fast.

Comment: gatoatigrado: They are not unboxed vectors, you are passing a `[Float]` to both calls of `nf`.  If you want to pass unboxed vectors then don't call `V.toList`.  Also, I'm running a 2.5GHz Intel Core 2.

Comment: I changed it to whnf evaluated on a Vector as you have it; there are no lists in the haarDWT codepath afaik.

Comment: gatoatigrado: What are you saying, exactly?  That `haarDWT` is slower than you expect?  I'd expect it to be slow, seeing as it uses `V.++`.

Comment: gatoatigrado: It looks like `V.++` was only costing you ~7%.  The real problem was haarStep splitting up the element access into two separate calls (causing double the cache misses, I bet, among other isues) - change those two things and the time goes from 133ms down to 21ms for the whole `haarDWT` function.  But as you said,, that's  another topic for another question.