# Haskell function execution time

Tags: haskell

Is there a simple method to compute time of function execution in Haskell?

Comment: the answers to my question about criterion may contain some helpful usage examples http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637968/how-to-use-criterion-to-measure-performance-of-haskell-programs .

Comment: Also, this is a somewhat nuanced situation, because functions don't have to be fully "executed" in Haskell. They just have to be expanded enough for whatever required value. Consider `head [1..]`, which takes the first element of an infinite list.

Comment: @gatoatigrado Thats why criterion has the `whnf` and `nf` functions.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

Simplest things is to just do `:set +s` in `ghci`, and then you can see the execution time of anything you run, along with memory usage.

Comment: Functions run much slower in ghci, however. In my test, about 10 times slower.

Comment: Is it possible to set the precision of the measured time, like in milliseconds?

Comment: Slower, yes, but this appears to be very valuable for demonstrating differences in time and space consumption between algorithms.  For example

<pre><code>
slow_fib :: Int -> Integer
slow_fib 0 = 0
slow_fib 1 = 1
slow_fib n = slow_fib (n-2) + slow_fib (n-1)

-- vs.

memoized_fib :: Int -> Integer
memoized_fib = (map fib [0 ..] !!)
   where fib 0 = 0
         fib 1 = 1
         fib n = memoized_fib (n-2) + memoized_fib (n-1)
</pre></code>

Where you can see the first function not only take up a LOT more time, but also several orders of magnitude more space.

Answer (score 30):

The [`criterion` package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/criterion/docs/Criterion-Main.html) was made specifically to do this well.

Answer (score 11):

See if http://hackage.haskell.org/package/timeit suits your needs.

Answer (score 7):

function execution time benchmark is included in [Criterion.Measurement](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/criterion-0.8.0.1/docs/Criterion-Measurement.html)

for example, if I want to capture the time of `someIOFunction :: IO ()`

```
import Criterion.Measurement
main = secs <$> time_ someIOFunction >>= print
```

Comment: This is no longer supported - seems deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

Criterion is the most sophisticated method, although I found it difficult to start, and it seems targeted to benchmarking programs. I wanted to compute the time of execution and use that data within my program and it doesn't seem to address this need, at least it's not immediately apparent.

TimeIt is very simple and does what I wanted, except it does not handle pure functions well. The time returned for a pure function is the thunk allocation time (AFAIK) and even with using seq it can be difficult to get what you want.

What is working for me is based on TimeIt.

```
import System.TimeIt

timeItTPure :: (a -> ()) -> a -> IO (Double,a)
timeItTPure p a = timeItT $ p a `seq` return a
```

In timeItTPure p a, p is the function responsible for evaluating the result of a pure calculation, a, as deeply as needed to get the good evaluation timing. Maybe this is a simple pattern match, maybe it's counting the length of a list, maybe its seq every element in the list, maybe its a deepseq, etc.

The use of seq is tricky. Note, the below function does not perform as desired. Haskell is a mysterious thing.

```
badTimeItTPure a = timeItT . return $ seq (p a) a
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to apply `timeItTPure`. How would I measure the execution time of a  function `f :: a -> a` applied to an argument `x :: a`? `timeItTPure f x` results in a type error, as `f` doesn't return `()`.

Comment: @erictapen you could try ``timeItT $ f x `seq` return x`` or ``timeItT $ let y = f x in y `seq` return y`` .

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/chrissound/FuckItTimer

```hs
start' <- start
timerc start' "begin"
print "hello"
timerc start' "after printing hello"
benchmark
timerc start' "end"
end <- getVals start'
forM_ (timert end) putStrLn
```

Outputs:

```
"hello"
begin -> after printing hello: 0.000039555s
after printing hello -> end: 1.333936928s
```

This seems to work fine for my very simple usecase.

Comment: Hmmmm.... Tried editing to get the highlighting right, but clearly it doesn't like me. Sorry.